# chrome extension doesnt auto-update. are my background listeners preventing auto update?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've noticed for my active users, my chrome extension arent auto updating(been a week).
but for my inactive users, the extension is auto updating.

Is it because of my 5+ listeners running in background.js?

- `persistent: false`
- my listeners opens ports from background to outside. and from content to background.
  If i remove those listeners, will it now auto update?

What is the best practice for extensions with background listeners to update the extension?

- close all listeners when idle, so that chrome can update? do people do this?
- use `chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener`, and either force update or have a user call to action?

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onUpdateAvailable

EDIT:

- is the reason why chrome extension not updating, because of my open port listeners in  background.js to ext website?

Comment: Use onUpdateAvailable and ask the user. If confirmed, call chrome.runtime.reload().

Comment: so you dont bother to removelisteners, and let chrome auto update? just do onUpdateAvailable?

Comment: Technically it's not necessary. You may want to do it if the other end is doing some cleanup in onDisconnect event.